# Windows wont boot after activating PCIe as primary video adapter

Tags: windows-10, boot, graphics-card, integrated-graphics

I’ve installed a new graphics card to my system (MSI GeForce GT1030). Before I used the integrated graphics card (Intel HD 4600) from the mainboard (Intel DH87RL).

The installation worked, I installed the newest nVidia drivers and the card shows up in Windows device manger. I was also able to run Geekbench 4 and achieved a score applicable for the GT1030.

The trouble starts when I deactivate the integrated graphics card and choose the GT1030 as the primary graphics card in my BIOS. The system starts booting and the display works fine but Windows will not start and the boot process is stuck and shows a dotted spinning circle.

Any ideas for a solution to this problem?

- OS: Windows 10 Pro
- RAM: 32 GB (4 x 8 GB DDR3-1600 Crucial Ballistix)
- HD: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500 GB  CPU: Core i5 4570S CPU-Z CPU
- Mainboard: Intel DH87RL (newest BIOS 07/20/2015)
- new graphics card: MSI GeForce GT1030
- integraded graphics card: Intel HD 4600

Answer (score 0):

try clearing cmos and reset bios to default settings.

Do not download the newest drivers for nvidia now. When I installed newest drivers same happened to me. Uninstall all nvidia drivers then clear cmos and bios.